# Instant search between different views AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, search, view, instant

I'm using ui-router in one AngularJs Project

I have two views like this:

```
.state('index', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
              '@' : {
                templateUrl: 'layout.html'
              },
              'top@index' : { templateUrl: 'partials/layout/top.html'},
              'main@index' : { templateUrl: 'partials/layout/main.html'}
            }
        })
```

Top and main.

Top view is a nav input search, Main view is where the results have to be displayed, filtering ng-repeat or whatever.

I need to search in the search box and the results must be displayed in the main view at the same time i'm typing in top view.

This only happens when I put the search box in the index.html, but it doesn't work when i put the search box in the top view.

Comment: please add more code by example, the controllers for the top@index and the controller for the main@index. Using `$scope.$broadcast` and `$scope.$on` methods it's possible to do it.

Comment: at this momment @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia the controlleres for top and main are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the combination of the `$rootScope.$broadcast` and `$scope.$on`. Basically you may put the $scope.$on in differents views and all the scopes subscribed to event executed by $rootScope in the `TopController` may listen the event.

In the top controller:

```
angular
     .module('exampleApp')
     .controller('TopController', TopController);

    TopController.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

    function TopController($rootScope){
        var vm = this;

        vm.search = function(textSearch) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('top:search', textSearch);
        }

    }
```

In the main controller:

```
$scope.$on('top:search', function(event, searchInput){
            console.log(searchInput);
        });
```

Check this: http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/eJzQpE